# problem saveOrUpdate object Hibernate (a different object with the same identifier session)

Tags: java, hibernate, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate: different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553200/hibernate-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associate)

I have problem when want update my object to database using hibernate
when I want update(branchDao.update(be);
) it's throw below exception

```
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

this my code:

```
            LoginEntity le = loginDao.getSpecificLogin(pkId);
            le.setPassword(password);
            le.setRoles(role);
            loginDao.update(le);               
            HumanEntity he = humanDao.getHumanById(humanID);  // humanEntuty farde morede nazar ro bar hasbe Email taraf load mikonad
            he.setHumanEmail(oemail);
            he.setHumanFamily(olname);
            he.setHumanName(ofname);
            humanDao.update(he);
            superBranchUsername = branch.getFatherUsername();
            int superBranchId = branchDao.getBranchIdByUserName(superBranchUsername);
            BranchEntity superBranch = branchDao.load(superBranchId);
            BranchEntity be = new BranchEntity();
            setBranchEntity(be, he, pkId, bname, confirmed, level, studentCount, uname, superBranch, le);
            branchDao.update(be); //this line throw exception
```

and for update :

```
 public void update(T transientObject) throws DatabaseException {
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = s.beginTransaction();
            s.update(transientObject);
            s.flush();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();

            throw new DatabaseException("cant't update object");
        }
    }
```

and this my BranchEntity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "branch", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"bname", "branch_fk"})})
public class BranchEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "username", length = 64, nullable = false)
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "bname", length = 64)
    private String branchName;
    @Column(name = "studcount")
    private int studCount;
    @Column(name = "blevel", columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int level;
    @Column(name = "confirmed", columnDefinition = "tinyint default 0")
    private int confirmed;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Set<BranchBuildingEntity> branchbuilding = new HashSet<BranchBuildingEntity>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Set<BranchPictureEntity> branchPicture = new HashSet<BranchPictureEntity>();
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)    
    @JoinColumn(name = "login_fk", nullable = true)
    private LoginEntity login;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "human_fk", nullable = true)
    private HumanEntity human;        
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "branch_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
    private BranchEntity superBranch;
```

Some where I read that problem because I use `@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)` but what shoud I do when I need cascade?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

org.hibernate.Session.update() is not for transient objects - it's for updating persistent objects. The message you quote "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" explains the problem. You create a brand new object

```
BranchEntity be = new BranchEntity();
```

fill its fields and pass it to update. But update expects an object that is associated with the session. So you should load the object using your dao, something like

```
BranchEntity be = branchDao.loadBranchEntity(...);
```

Comment: or you should use save/saveOrUpdate if you actually do want to create a new object.