# Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate: different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553200/hibernate-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associate)

I have got almost the same problem like that [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074081/hibernate-error-org-hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception-a-different-object-with).

In my situation I load one entity from db, I convert this entity into a DataTransferObject, then I want to edit one attribute, after that I convert it back into an entityObject, then I update that entity and hibernate throws following error:

```
Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

Apparently, the problem is that the object I retrieve from db has the same id as the one I want to update (like it should be) BUT those are not the same objects!

How to manage that?
Thank you for help...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your problem is that the object you previously loaded still exists in your hibernate session. I see two ways to cope with that.

1.) tell the hibernate session to merge your modified object with the one in the session

```
session.merge(object)
```

2.) kick the old object out of the session before writing the updated object to the session. session.clear() might work.

Comment: merge() didn't work for me. I tried clear() and evict(object) with success

Comment: @Silentbang. Yes I had to do both 'clear()' and 'evict(object)`. Seems like one or the other alone should work, but need both.

Answer (score 16):

This is a very common problem with Hibernate. Even if you delete it from the session, the object will stay in Hibernate PersistanceContext and you will have the same problem. The problem is also coming from the fact that session.contains uses object equality, and not `equals()` to compare the object...

The story is the following: you have object A and object B,which are the same logical object, but two different objects in your java heap.  and you have long time ago did something with object A in the session.

Now if you do `session.delete(B)` you will get the exception, because you are trying to delete an object which has the same primary key as A, but is not A.

The solution is simple:

```
Object findAAgain=session.merge(B);
session.delete(findAAgain);
```

the merge returns the instance of the object you have in the session first.

Comment: This was really helpful. I have tried session.evict() a lot of times without success.

Answer (score 4):

choose either one:

1 - you can close the session after loading the entity and open new session for update

2 - instead of creating new Entity for update, use the old one and edit it.

3 - detach your first entity from session - `session.evict(myEntity)`

Comment: Thank you for your ideas but I don't want to close the session and my architecture doesn't let me update the old object (besides a lot of effort)

Comment: @Sven can you detach entity from session?

Comment: doesn't work: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

Answer (score 0):

Beyond just calling `clear()` on the session, it sounds like you might have a problem with the way you are using Hibernate:

> Apparently, the problem is that the object I retrieve from db has the same id as the one I want to update (like it should be) BUT those are not the same objects!

Do you mean to say that you have two distinct entities which have the same ID? If so, then you should find a different field that uniquely identifies different entities.

Comment: No they are the same logical objects/ the same entities but java gives them different object-id's

Comment: how are the `<id>`s generated? what scheme are you using?