# session in hibernate(save two object once)

Tags: hibernate, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate: different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553200/hibernate-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associate)

I tried to save two entity once:

```
session=....getCurrentSession();

Book bo1=new Book();
bo1.setName("name1");
session.save(bo1);

Book bo2=new Book();
bo2.setName("name2");
session.save(bo2);
```

Then I get a exception:

> a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.

Seems that the bo2' identifier exist (the bo1's identifier), I wonder why?

BTW, I really want to know more about the session in hibernate, any docs? I have read the tutorial of hibernate, but it is not detailed enough.

Comment: you should put more information about how you are handling the entities ID!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide Book mapping. I difficult to know what can happen behind the scenes if you just show some snippet of code. We help you if you help us. But a good intro to SessionFactory/Session is shown [here](http://acupof.blogspot.com/2008/01/background-hibernate-comes-with-three.html). Good lucky!

Comment: Thanks I got it, I found that it is caused by the type of the generator,I set it to identify,and it work now.