# How to commit non-session objects using Hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate: different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553200/hibernate-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associate)

I am working with Hibernate and Struts 1. My web application is running on one machine and my Hibernate code on another. I am using web services to access the database. My problem is that when I attempt to update any object it throws "org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException", when I call commit via my service method.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object
>   with the same identifier value was already associated with the
>   session: [**.**.emp#2]

I am unable to find the what the problem is, but I think when I retrieve the object for editing, it gets attached to the Hibernate session and then when I attempt an update it creates a new object on the service side as I am deserializing the object, so there may be two object with same identifier.

Does anyone have any insight into what might be going on with this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`merge`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29) your detached objects back into the Hibernate Session prior to committing them. Using the (legacy) HibernateUtil class, your code would look something like:

```
final Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
// ...
session.merge(entity);
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912659/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-attach-detached-objects-in-hibernate).