# Hibernate Serialize/Deserialize Object and save it

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, serialization

I have an Object of my POJO Class and I saved it on my **Redis** *(NoSql)* server as `byte[]`.

Now I When I get the object back from the Redis server, make some changes and call `session.saveOrUpdate()`, it throws an exception.

`a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with 
the session`

I am using `SerializationHelper` class to `serialize()` and `deserialize()` the object and its working fine.

Is there any way in Hibernate that I can save that deserialize object.

Comment: Throws "an exception", eh?  Which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate: different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553200/hibernate-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveOrUpdate()` tries to attach a detached (or transient) object to the session.

Since Hibernate guarantees that a session does never holds 2 instances of the same attached entity, it throws this exception.

If you want to copy the state of a detached object to an attached one, use `session.merge()` (which returns the attached, modified object).